# How to check that this empty object caused by empty json output is really empty?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a json web service that returns simply `[]`.
Then, I have a javascript Object variable `json_var` that contains this json output. When json returns empty `[]`, `json_var` is `undefined`. How do I check from the content of `json_var` that the json output is empty `[]`?

Comment: If the reply is `[]`, then your variable should be set to an empty array, not `undefined`.  Something is amiss in your code.

Comment: @Mark Reed: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Why the negative vote? Please tell me what is wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for the `length` of the response. As it was mentioned `[]` refers to an empty *array*

```
var test = [];
console.log(test.length); // returns 0
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wm3o24dk/)**